# Show that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n$ iff $\mathrm{rref} A$ has no zero columns.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Show that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=n$ iff $\mathrm{rref}A$ has no zero columns, using only the definition of rank and reduced row echelon form ($\mathrm{rref}$).

**My attempt:** If $\mathrm{rref}A$ has no zero columns, suppose $\mathrm{rank}(A)< n$. For every row $i=1,\ldots,k$, let $j_i$ be the column in which he first non-zero entry of row $i$ appears. Note that $$\{j_1,...j_k\}\subset\{1,...,n\}.$$
This implies that there is at least one column $j_i$ in which there isn't a first non-zero entry of any row $i$. The problem is that I haven't proved that the previously mentioned column is a zero column.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show your attempt. What is rref?

Comment: My attempt:
If rrefA has no zero columns. Suppose rank(A)<n.
For every row i=1,..,k, let j_i be the column in which he first non zero entry of row i appears. 
Note that {j_1,...j_k}\subset{1,...,n}. This implies that there is at least one column j_i in which there isnt a first non zero entry of any row i.
The problem is that I havent proved that the previously mentioned column is a zero column.

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to think of this in terms of rows.

By definition, the rank is the number of pivots in the rref of $A$ (your definition may differ).  However, every row can have at most one pivot (by the definition of rref). If a row does not contain a pivot, then (again, by the definition of rref) it is a pivot row.

So, suppose that the rank of $A$ is $n$. There are $n$ rows, so every row must have a pivot.  So, there are no zero rows in the rref.

Conversely suppose that $A$ has a zero row.  Then there is a row that has no pivot.  So, there must be less than $n$ pivots overall, which means that the rank is less than $n$.